# custom field for subscribe page?

Tags: custom-fields, forms

is it possible to add custom field in :

```
http:/drupalsite.com/civicrm/mailing/subscribe?reset=1
```

I tried looking for custom field additional in the settings but not available?
is there a hook needed to process?

as its only collecting one email info for now?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can replicate the functionality by creating a Profile which includes the 'public' groups you want users to sign up for.

A second approach is to use the webform_civicrm module where you can similarly include specific Groups and any other custom fields you want.

I don't think adding a field to civicrm/mailing/subscribe?reset=1 is available through the UI.